# What's the correlation coefficient of $N$ and $M$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$N, M \sim Poi(1)$ on the intervals $(0,2)$ and $(1,3)$.
What's the value of $Corr(N,M)$?

My attempt was to define $X \sim Poi(1)$ on $(0,1)$. Now the question is $Corr(2X,2X+1)=?$
Which is 
$$Corr(2X+1,2X)=\frac{\mathbb{E}((2X+1)(2X))-\mathbb{E}(2X+1)\mathbb{E}(2X)}{\mathbb{D}(2X+1)\mathbb{D}(2X)}=\frac{1}{4}(4\mathbb{E}(X^2)+2\mathbb{E}(X)-\mathbb{E}(2X)^2+2\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{4}(4\frac{2}{1^2}+2-4+2)=2$$

I'm not really confident that this is a good solution. Can you help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be  best to say that $M$ and $N$ refer to the same interval $(0,3)$ in which Poisson events occur. // If $2X = N,$ then $2X+1$ can't be $M.$ You need three mutually indep RVs for 'independent increments' $(0,1), (1,2), (2,3),$ respectively. Please see my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe best to go back a step and look at the covariance.
Let $M = L + X$ and $N = X + R,$ where $L, X, R$ are independent
$\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 1/2).$ Then
$$Cov(M,N) = Cov(L + X, X + R) = \cdots = Var(X) = 1/2.$$
Perhaps you can take it from there.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot.